# Node.js crashing

Tags: node.js

My node.js app keeps crashing.  It's a simple web service that gets data from a mysql database.  I get about 20k to 30k queries a day.  I'm not sure if it's crashing because I need to give it more resources or if I have a problem with my code.  It's hosted in AppFog and here's the crashlog.

I'm not sure what the hashish package is but I tried installing it using 'npm install hashish' and it didn't fix the problem.

Any thoughts?

```
C:\Users\Tom\\nodejs>af crashlogs TomsApp
====> /logs/staging.log <====

# Logfile created on 2013-02-05 00:53:01 +0000 by logger.rb/25413
Installing dependencies. Node version 0.8.14
Installing mysql@mysql@0.9.6 from local path
Installing hashish@hashish@0.0.4 from registry
Package is not found in npm registry hashish@hashish@0.0.4
Failed getting the requested package: hashish@hashish@0.0.4
Installing require-all@require-all@0.0.5 from local path

====> /logs/stderr.log <====


events.js:71
        throw arguments[1]; // Unhandled 'error' event
                       ^
Error: Connection lost: The server closed the connection.
    at Protocol.end (/mnt/var/vcap.local/dea/apps/ta-0-365d7313671d4e40105a4d158
f1247d5/app/node_modules/mysql/lib/protocol/Protocol.js:63:13)
    at Socket.onend (stream.js:66:10)
    at Socket.EventEmitter.emit (events.js:126:20)
    at TCP.onread (net.js:417:51)
```

Comment: I figured out the hashish error.  It had to do with my npm-shrinkwrap.json and package.json files.  What I had installed was different than what was in my package.json file and shrinkwrap.json was having issues with it.  All I had to do is install the correct packages that corresponded with package.json.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How are you getting your connection?  Do you get it once, or get a new one for each request and then return it to the pool?  The pool should be handling stale connections behind the scene.

```
var mysql = require('mysql');
var pool  = mysql.createPool({
  host     : 'example.org',
  user     : 'bob',
  password : 'secret'
});


// for each request where you need the database connection, wrap it with
pool.getConnection(function(err, connection) {
  // do something with connection here
  ...
  connection.end();
});
```

Comment: Good idea.  I'll try that.  That should help with the heavy traffic, right?

Comment: just make sure you have enough connections in your pool, and that the database can accept a number higher than your pool needs.

Comment: I implemented pooling.  I'm still getting Connection Lost errors but it seems to be running a little better.  I also added the connection.end() code which I figure should help.  I set the pool size to 100 but I have no idea what appfogs limit is.

Answer (score 1):

I would say mysql server's refusing the connection maybe you want to look into that

Answer (score 0):

You probably have to handle the error event on the socket (http://nodejs.org/api/net.html#net_event_error_1) for all your connections.

That will keep it from crashing and you should then see the actual problem.

Comment: Cool.  Thanks.  I added the error handling code so now we wait to see what it comes from that.  Any thoughts on the part of the log that talks about 'hashish'?

Comment: I'm now seeing these errors:  Re-connecting lost connection: Error: Connection lost: The server closed the con
nection.
    at Protocol.end (/mnt/var/vcap.local/dea/apps/ta-0-5c083ea6143fd3e9b24d1e082
ab5ce14/app/node_modules/mysql/lib/protocol/Protocol.js:72:13)
    at Socket.onend (stream.js:66:10)
    at Socket.EventEmitter.emit (events.js:126:20)
    at TCP.onread (net.js:417:51)